# Can nginx log to an arbitrary UDP socket?

Tags: nginx, logging

Is it possible to make nginx log its access logs to an arbitrary UDP socket, logging only the output of the log format?

The syslog facility comes close but seems to insist on adding a header with the timestamp, hostname and programname.  I'm trying to log to a service that accepts a JSON-formatted payload.  I've written an nginx log_format that produces a JSON document, but can't figure out how to get it to produce *only* that.

Comment: i think you have to convert the output by using http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html a other option isnt known to me. You may also modify the output by using a custom log format

Comment: @djdomi I'd found the log_format directive but when you log that to syslog, it still prepends an RFC3164 header, even if the message contains a valid RFC5424 header.  On digging further, the reason for this seems to be that nginx just uses the system libc's `syslog(3)` call and glibc's still uses RFC3164.  Use nginx on *bsd and it generates RFC5424 headers.

Comment: you may want to add or solve your question on your own i think noone else will do that ;)